# No Write Access on Wordpress Folder permissions for Bitnami running on AWS

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, permissions, bitnami

I recently migrated my Wordpress sites to Bitnami on Amazon Web Services.  Everything it up and running from the user's perspective, but I'm struggling with a minor permission issue with the themes folder.  When I download (or upload my own) theme, it doesn't have write permissions.  Bitnami has this as the default for security purposes but when I had my stuff hosted at GoDaddy, this issue never came up.

The odd time I like to go and edit a theme file directly from Wordpress.  I also have a File Manager plugin installed that I'll sometimes use instead of FTP to upload theme files.

I can manually change the permissions, either in FileZilla or using SSH but my curiosity and stubbornness would like to have write permission by default on any themes, new or existing.

Do I need to edit a config file somewhere to make this happen?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to connect to your server via SSH and execute the commands below described in order to assign correct permissions definitively:

```
sudo chmod -R g+w /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content
sudo chown -R bitnami:daemon /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content
```

Then check again if your themes works as you expected.

You can read our documentation to clarify all this situation: https://docs.bitnami.com/general/apps/wordpress/

Comment: Unsure to replace the paths if needed